# What is the usage of adding 'ao' to the ending of words?

Tags: significado

I'm now learning this wonderful song be Celia Cruz named *La Negra Tiene Tumba'o*

I've read the following about adding 'ao' to the ending of Spanish words:

> The 'ao' at the end of some of the words is simply a shortened form of
> 'ado,' the ending of a past participle:
>
> encontrao = encontrado
>
> apretao = apretado
>
> For others, it is used as a rhyming mechanism, but happens to also be
> how many people pronounce the words and the spelling follows suit:
>
> lao = lado (side - de lao = 'sideways')
>
> melao = melado (honey color - could also mean honey and a form of
> speaking or language)

Is there a Native speaker that can co-sign on the above?

Also, being that the late and great Celia Cruz was Cuban, is this something that is common only by Cuban Spanish speakers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pronunciation of *-ado* as /áo/ or even /áu/ is very common throughout Cuba and the entire Spanish-speaking world. It happens to a lesser extent with other vowel-D-vowel combinations, mostly word-finally but occasionally elsewhere, too like in *cantaor(a)* or *aonde*.

The sound that the D makes in Spanish in between vowels is very weak, and in some dialects you'd be hard-pressed to find someone who pronounces the D outside of very careful speech.

At the moment, you'll hear D enough, though, that no one is going to do a spelling change, but there is clear precedence for it happening. The *vos(otros)* form for *-ar* verbs used to be *-ades* (still seen in some poetry when it fits the rhyme better), but it quickly became closer to *ayes*/*ayis*/*áïs* and then *áis* (thence *ái* or *ás* for modern voseo).

Comment: And when the two vowels are the same, they are often shortened to one in relaxed pronunciation: *nada* becomes *na*, *todo* becomes *to*, and *puede* becomes *pue*.

Comment: @Yay OMG, more complication for the Spanish learner. Hahaa! I hope to one day have my ears trained for this. :)

Comment: @RockAnthony I'm sure you will! Just keep in mind dropping the "d", especially when that reduces the word by one syllable, may be seen as too informal or out of place in certain contexts. Regional differences also play an important role, but in general terms I'd recommend not doing it unless you hear other people do it too.

Comment: The word _hoosegow_ for ‘prison’ is said to come from Spanish _juzgado_ ‘judged’.

Comment: Changing -ido for -ío is also very common.